# Assigning different weights to search keywords

Tags: python, nlp

I'm implementing a search engine and so far I am done with the part for web crawling, storing the results in the index and retrieving results for the search keywords entered by the user. However I would like the search results to be more specific. Let's say I'm searching "Shoe shops in Hyderabad". Is there any NLP library in python that can just process the text and assign higher weights on important words like in this case "shoes" and "Hyderabad".

Thanks.

Comment: Too broad, I'm afraid, an why are "shoe" and "Hyderabad" important words but not "shops"?

Comment: Because "Shoes in Hyderabad" and "Shoe shops in Hyderabad" are expected to return more or less the same kind of results if a google search is done.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think one approach is going to solve the entire problem here. Your question is broad and it will take multiple steps to get best results. Here is how I would approach the problem

1. Create N-grams analyser with Lucene and query. Lucene also allows
   `Phrase queries`. `Shoe shops in Hyderabad` is a good fit for that.
2. Use cosine similarity to treat `Shoe shops in Hyderabad` and `Footwear shops in Hyderabad` similarly.
3. Also think of some linguistic angle. Simple POS tagging and role based rule engine can help you get much smarter results for queries like `Shoe shops in Hyderabad` or `Shoe under 500 bucks` where a very finite word set of `in, under, on etc` can be assigned rules on `location/ comparison` etc. This point assumes you are looking at English language. You will have to build this layer separately for each language though.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I think the question is good (I was looking something similar last week) and of course as other people mention the question is too broad. But I think you can face it using a information Retrieval system. I can recommend you Lemur project and spefically [**Indri**](https://www.lemurproject.org/indri/), it includes a lot of customization features for queries, then is possible weighting using n-grams, tf-idf (as previuos two answer suggest) or just use you own criteria. If you want use Indri, check [this](http://www.iro.umontreal.ca/~nie/IFT6255/indri.ppt) is an tutorial/introduction, and something about weighting is at **page 56**.

Good look!

Comment: I think one of the services in my org is solving the problem. Although it does not rank the words on priority but given a text, it does return a list of important words or keywords from the text. I'm hoping that should help me.